# matlab stem parametres

Tags: matlab

I am using "**stem**" command to plot discrete values into figure. I dont know how to remove the line connecting the points to the x-axis. I found a lot of parametres that changes the shape and color of the line but none that would remove it.

```
stem(X, Y)
```

Is there a way how to do this or am I using wrong command? Plot and bar is not what Im looking for...

I somewhere saw this:

```
stem(X, Y, 'none')
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: The line is the whole purpose of the `stem` command.  If you don't want it, try a different plotting command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,10);
h = stem(t,cos(t),'LineStyle','none');
```